# python pandas - get matching and non matching records between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I'm new to use pandas in python whereas I have good knowledge in working with python.

I've two data frames from which I've to get matching records and non matching records into new data frames.

Example :

DF1 :

```
ID Name Number    DOB     Salary
1  AAA  1234   12-05-1996 100000
2  BBB  1235   16-08-1997 200000
3  CCC  1236   24-04-1998 389999
4  DDD  1237   05-09-2000 450000
```

DF2 :

```
ID Name Number    DOB     Salary
1  AAA  1234   12-05-1996 100000
2  BBB  1235   16-08-1997 200000
3  CCC  1236   24-04-1998 389999
4  DDD  1237   05-09-2000 540000
```

And, with primary keys being ID & Name here(in reality the number of keys might vary), I need to get

Match_df :

```
ID Name Number    DOB     Salary
1  AAA  1234   12-05-1996 100000
2  BBB  1235   16-08-1997 200000
3  CCC  1236   24-04-1998 389999
```

Mismatch_df :

```
ID Name Number    DOB     Salary
4  DDD  1237   05-09-2000 540000
```

I've tried all possible ways like

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=[ID,Name],right_on=[ID,Name], how='inner')
```

and this produces all the unique keys that are in both the data frames. But this also produces non matching records.

But I'm getting this as my result :

```
ID Name Number    DOB     Salary
1  AAA  1234   12-05-1996 100000
2  BBB  1235   16-08-1997 200000
3  CCC  1236   24-04-1998 389999
4  DDD  1237   05-09-2000 540000
```

where 4th record is also getting included.

Here, only salary col is varying but in real Time, it may be a list of cols to be compared.

From this, I've to get only matching records to the matched_df and non matching records to the mismatch_df.

Kindly help me out in doing this.

> Note: My dataset might be a massive one (100 million records in both datasets) so, please get me an effective approach reducing the time of execution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have multiple answers you can use one to clear this question from the un-answered Queue.

Comment: yes, but actually I'm still working around this. That's why I'm still holding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# pick index keys and compare column(s)
keys = ['ID', 'Name']
# if comparing all columns:
col_list = [col for col in df1.columns if col not in keys]
# # if comparing specific columns:
# col_list = ['Salary', 'DOB']

# extend keys with col_list for next step
sel_cols = keys.copy()
sel_cols.extend(col_list)

# set a multi-index with keys
# to dataframes with col_list columns
dfa = df1[sel_cols].set_index(keys)
dfb = df2[sel_cols].set_index(keys)

# make an equivalency boolean mask
dfa.update(dfb)
mask = np.equal(df1[col_list].values, dfa.values).all(axis=1)

# slice df1 with mask
Match_df = df1[mask]
Mismatch_df = df1[~mask]
```

Comment: this throws "Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!" error when I pass list of cols in place of 'salary'.....

Comment: OK didn't understand you were comparing more than one column.  Standby.

Comment: I'll update this further shortly to remove the loop - does this work as is for you now?

Comment: Removed loop and made it easy to compare all columns or selected columns only.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yours is just awesome. I just had to make some more changes to get my work done as desired. Thank you too much !!!!

Answer (score 7):

**Simplistic Answer to your question is with `df1.where` :**

**Note:** The resulting cells with NaN do not satisfy the conditions, i.e. they are not equal in the two dataframes. The ones that have a real value are the ones that are equal in the two dataframes

```
>>> df1.where(df1.Salary==df2.Salary)
          DoB   ID  Name    Salary
0  12-05-1996  1    AAA  100000.0
1  16-08-1997  2    BBB  200000.0
2  24-04-1998  3    CCC  389999.0
3         NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
```

While going with `pd.merge`: If you Just want to merge the df1 & df1 without Column or index level then it will take defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2)
          DoB  ID Name  Salary
0  12-05-1996   1  AAA  100000
1  16-08-1997   2  BBB  200000
2  24-04-1998   3  CCC  389999
```

If you wish to Join Column or index level then use `on`.

```
 >>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Salary")
        DoB_x  ID_x Name_x  Salary       DoB_y  ID_y Name_y
0  12-05-1996     1    AAA  100000  12-05-1996     1    AAA
1  16-08-1997     2    BBB  200000  16-08-1997     2    BBB
2  24-04-1998     3    CCC  389999  24-04-1998     3    CCC
```

**For mismatch in `df2`:**  you can opt [isin(dict)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method:

```
>>> df2[~df2.isin(df1.to_dict('l')).all(1)]
          DoB  ID Name  Salary
3  05-09-2000   4  DDD  540000
```

another way as Mabel given.

```
df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time in answering my question, I've given an upvote but I don't think that will reflect as I'm new contributor...

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be a bit different and would involve simply copying the salary from the other dataset over.

Such as:

```
DF1["Salary2"] = DF2["Salary"]

MatchDF = DF1[DF1["Salary"] == DF1["Salary2"]]
MisMatchDF = DF1[DF1["Salary"] != DF1["Salary2"]]
```

Comment: But actually my real dataset might contain 'n' number of columns to check for and doing so would make my code hard coded and also might result in poor performance......

Comment: I meant more you should try to merge but leave the salary columns intact, and then do a comparison after the fact. Might be easier. But I'm a novice too

Comment: Thanks for giving your view, I've given an upvote but I don't think that will reflect as I'm new contributor...

Answer (score 0):

To get the match:

```
>> df1.merge(df2)

ID Name  Number         DOB  Salary
0   1  AAA    1234  12-05-1996  100000
1   2  BBB    1235  16-08-1997  200000
2   3  CCC    1236  24-04-1998  389999
```

And for the mismatch selecting the row in `df2`:

```
>> df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(axis=1)]

   Name  Number         DOB  Salary
ID                                 
4   DDD    1237  05-09-2000  540000
```